# How to handle exceptions in OnNext when using ObserveOn?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

My application terminates when an error is thrown in `OnNext` by an observer when I use `ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)`. The only way I have found to deal with this is by using a custom extension method below (apart from making sure OnNext never throws an exception). And then making sure that each `ObserveOn` is followed by an `ExceptionToError`.

```
    public static IObservable<T> ExceptionToError<T>(this IObservable<T> source) {
        var sub = new Subject<T>();
        source.Subscribe(i => {
            try {
                sub.OnNext(i);
            } catch (Exception err) {
                sub.OnError(err);
            }
        }
            , e => sub.OnError(e), () => sub.OnCompleted());
        return sub;
    }
```

However, this does not feel right. Is there a better way to deal with this?

**Example**

This program crashes because of uncaught exception.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        try {
            var xs = new Subject<int>();

            xs.ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool).Subscribe(x => {
                Console.WriteLine(x);
                if (x % 5 == 0) {
                    throw new System.Exception("Bang!");
                }
            }, ex => Console.WriteLine("Caught:" + ex.Message)); // <- not reached

            xs.OnNext(1);
            xs.OnNext(2);
            xs.OnNext(3);
            xs.OnNext(4);
            xs.OnNext(5);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Caught : " + e.Message); // <- also not reached
        } finally {

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We're addressing this issue in Rx v2.0, starting with the RC release. You can read all about it on our blog at http://blogs.msdn.com/rxteam. It basically boils down to more disciplined error handling in the pipeline itself, combined with a SubscribeSafe extension method (to redirect errors during subscription into the OnError channel), and a Catch extension method on IScheduler (to wrap a scheduler with exception handling logic around scheduled actions).

Concerning the ExceptionToError method proposed here, it has one flaw. The IDisposable subscription object can still be null when the callbacks run; there's a fundamental race condition. To work around this, you'd have to use a SingleAssignmentDisposable.

Comment: The link http://blogs.msdn.com/rxteam to the blog is broken. Anywhere else this information is described so the answer can be updated?

Comment: I think this is the archived blog he referred to : https://web.archive.org/web/20120629033234/https://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/06/17/reactive-extensions-v2-0-release-candidate-available-now.aspx

Answer (score 7):

There's a difference between errors in subscription and errors in the observable. A quick test:

```
var xs = new Subject<int>();

xs.Subscribe(x => { Console.WriteLine(x); if (x % 3 == 0) throw new System.Exception("Error in subscription"); }, 
             ex => Console.WriteLine("Error in source: " + ex.Message));
```

Run with this and you'll get a nice handled error in the source:

```
xs.OnNext(1);
xs.OnNext(2);
xs.OnError(new Exception("from source"));
```

Run with this and you'll get an unhandled error in the subscription:

```
xs.OnNext(1);
xs.OnNext(2);
xs.OnNext(3);
```

**What your solution has done is take errors in the subscription and make them errors in the source**. And you've done this on the original stream, rather than on a per subscription basis. You may or may not have intended to do this, but it's almost certainly wrong.

The 'right' way to do it is to add the error handling you need directly to the subscribing action, which is where it belongs. If you don't want to modify your subscription functions directly, you can use a little helper:

```
public static Action<T> ActionAndCatch<T>(Action<T> action, Action<Exception> catchAction)
{
    return item =>
    {
        try { action(item); }
        catch (System.Exception e) { catchAction(e); }
    };
}
```

And now to use it, again showing the difference between the different errors:

```
xs.Subscribe(ActionAndCatch<int>(x => { Console.WriteLine(x); if (x % 3 == 0) throw new System.Exception("Error in subscription"); },
                                 ex => Console.WriteLine("Caught error in subscription: " + ex.Message)),
             ex => Console.WriteLine("Error in source: " + ex.Message));
```

Now we can handle (separately) errors in the source and error in the subscription. Of course, any of these actions can be defined in a method, making the above code as simple as (potentially):

```
xs.Subscribe(ActionAndCatch(Handler, ExceptionHandler), SourceExceptionHandler);
```

**Edit**

In the comments we then started discussing the fact that errors in the subscription are pointing to errors in the stream itself, and you wouldn't want other subscribers on that stream. This is a *completely different type of issue*. I would be inclined to write an observable `Validate` extension to handle this scenario:

```
public static IObservable<T> Validate<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Predicate<T> valid)
{
    return Observable.Create<T>(o => {
        return source.Subscribe(
            x => {
                if (valid(x)) o.OnNext(x);
                else       o.OnError(new Exception("Could not validate: " + x));
            }, e => o.OnError(e), () => o.OnCompleted()
        );
    });
}
```

Then simple to use, without mixing metaphors (errors only in source):

```
xs
.Validate(x => x != 3)
.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x),
             ex => Console.WriteLine("Error in source: " + ex.Message));
```

If you still want suppressed exceptions in `Subscribe` you should use one of the other discussed methods.

Comment: I agree that making it an error in the source might not be correct. However, with your solution each observer must do error handling themselves. My approach could be changed to `ExceptionToAction<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Action<Exception> handler)`. Either way, it feels not quite right to me yet.

Comment: I don't really understand. In every case you need to provide an exception handler. Either you can attach the exception handler at subscription time (the preferred method), or you can attach the exception handler to the source observable. The latter goes against general RX design since you're modifying a future subscription on your observable, rather than the observable itself. Very 'side effectful'. Your suggested change (`ExceptionToAction`) is at minimum needed, but it still doesn't make it explicit that this is exceptions in subscription.

Comment: Also note you say "each observer must do error handling themselves". If you wish to 'extend' something, perhaps create a standard observer that handles the errors, and just that one? That's essentially what `ActionAndCatch` is, except it's the bare minimum observer for `OnNext`.

Comment: That is an interesting idea! Something like a `SubscribeAndCatch`. My goals are two-fold: 1) I would like a safety net, to make sure not my entire app crashes when there is an exception in a stream, and 2) prevent invalid data in streams. The safety net has to be at the source (or scheduler?) to catch everything, and the other would likely be near the observer. In my case missing one value invalidates the stream, so calling `OnError` seems the right choice to me but I might be mistaking?

Comment: Well now we're talking about invalid data in streams! OK according to this bad boy (Rx Design Guidelines: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205219) no exceptions should be thrown in Subscribe, but they *should* be tunnelled back into the stream in order to stop it. This is the scenario you're after - killing a stream on certain conditions. So, in other words, go ahead and create a custom operator using `Observable.Create` (or a combination of `SelectMany`, `Return` and `Throw`) and use it to validate the stream. But handle errors in subscription (which are a different beast) elsewhere.

Comment: Also, you're right - if missing one value invalidates the stream then the subscribe method should also reinject errors back into the stream as a side effect of what they are doing. I like an extension method called `MergeSubscriptionErrors` and implemented as done by @Enigmativity.

Comment: Your pointers actually helped me fix a problem in my RxJava project. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4):

Your current solution is not ideal. As stated by one of the Rx people [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/ee5dba5d-eea9-4d85-8f58-c2e1c71ef33a):

> Rx operators do not catch exceptions that occur in a call to OnNext, OnError, or OnCompleted.  This is because we expect that (1) the observer implementor knows best how to handle those exceptions and we can't do anything reasonable with them and (2) if an exception occurs then we want that to bubble out and not be handled by Rx.

Your current solution gets the IObservable to handle errors thrown by the IObserver, which doesn't make sense as semantically the IObservable should have no knowledge of the things observing it. Consider the following example:

```
var errorFreeSource = new Subject<int>();
var sourceWithExceptionToError = errorFreeSource.ExceptionToError();
var observerThatThrows = Observer.Create<int>(x =>
  {
      if (x % 5 == 0)
          throw new Exception();
  },
  ex => Console.WriteLine("There's an argument that this should be called"),
  () => Console.WriteLine("OnCompleted"));
var observerThatWorks = Observer.Create<int>(
    x => Console.WriteLine("All good"),
    ex => Console.WriteLine("But definitely not this"),
    () => Console.WriteLine("OnCompleted"));
sourceWithExceptionToError.Subscribe(observerThatThrows);
sourceWithExceptionToError.Subscribe(observerThatWorks);
errorFreeSource.OnNext(1);
errorFreeSource.OnNext(2);
errorFreeSource.OnNext(3);
errorFreeSource.OnNext(4);
errorFreeSource.OnNext(5);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Here there is no issue with the source, or the observerThatWorks, but its OnError will be called due to an unrelated error with another Observer. To stop exceptions in a different thread from ending the process, you'll have to catch them in that thread, so put a try/catch block in your observers.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the native [`SubscribeSafe`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/0e14e288bcfbe97f47ddf915d57f1acd20a61a5b/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Observable.Extensions.cs#L365) method that is supposed to solve this problem, but I can't make it work. This method has a single overload that accepts an `IObserver<T>`:

```
// Subscribes to the specified source, re-routing synchronous exceptions during
// invocation of the IObservable<T>.Subscribe(IObserver<T>) method to the
// observer's IObserver<T>.OnError(Exception) channel. This method is typically
// used when writing query operators.
public static IDisposable SubscribeSafe<T>(this IObservable<T> source,
    IObserver<T> observer);
```

I tried passing an observer created by the [`Observer.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh211985(v=vs.103)) factory method, but the exceptions in the `onNext` handler continue crashing the process¹, just like they do with the normal `Subscribe`. So I ended up writing my own version of `SubscribeSafe`. This one accepts three handlers as arguments, and funnels any exceptions thrown by the `onNext` and `onCompleted` handlers to the `onError` handler.

```
/// <summary>Subscribes an element handler, an error handler, and a completion
/// handler to an observable sequence. Any exceptions thrown by the element or
/// the completion handler are propagated through the error handler.</summary>
public static IDisposable SubscribeSafe<T>(this IObservable<T> source,
    Action<T> onNext, Action<Exception> onError, Action onCompleted)
{
    // Arguments validation omitted
    var disposable = new SingleAssignmentDisposable();
    disposable.Disposable = source.Subscribe(
        value =>
        {
            try { onNext(value); } catch (Exception ex) { onError(ex); disposable.Dispose(); }
        }, onError, () =>
        {
            try { onCompleted(); } catch (Exception ex) { onError(ex); }
        }
    );
    return disposable;
}
```

Beware, an unhandled exception in the `onError` handler will still crash the process!

¹ <sub>Only exceptions thrown when the handler is invoked asynchronously on the `ThreadPool`.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You're right - it should feel bad. Using and returning subjects like this is not a good way to go.

At the very least you should implement this method like so:

```
public static IObservable<T> ExceptionToError<T>(this IObservable<T> source)
{
    return Observable.Create<T>(o =>
    {
        var subscription = (IDisposable)null;
        subscription = source.Subscribe(x =>
        {
            try
            {
                o.OnNext(x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                o.OnError(ex);
                subscription.Dispose();
            }
        }, e => o.OnError(e), () => o.OnCompleted());
        return subscription;
    });
}
```

Notice there are no subjects used and that if I catch an error that I then dispose of the subscription to prevent the sequence continuing past an error.

However, why not just add an `OnError` handler in your subscription. A bit like this:

```
var xs = new Subject<int>();

xs.ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool).Subscribe(x =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    if (x % 5 == 0)
    {
        throw new System.Exception("Bang!");
    }
}, ex => Console.WriteLine(ex.Message));

xs.OnNext(1);
xs.OnNext(2);
xs.OnNext(3);
xs.OnNext(4);
xs.OnNext(5);
```

This code catches the error properly in the subscription.

The other method is to use the `Materialize` extension method, but that may be a little overkill unless the above solutions don't work.

Comment: The OnError is not called in your OnError example, unless the ExceptionToError is added (tried using console app and with unit test project). Did you test it? Many thanks to the improvement of the ExceptionToError, however it still feels unnatural. Maybe error handling should be added to the scheduler? Ie a SafeScheduler wrapper.

Comment: I have looked into `Materialize` but do not see how I can use that. The OnError is not called without the `ExceptionToError`. Tested it with:

        public static IObservable<T> Log<T>(IObservable<T> source) {
            return source.Materialize().Select(n => {
                Trace.WriteLine("Error hunt: " + n);
                   return n;
               }).Dematerialize();
        }

Comment: @Herman - Can you provide some code that demostrates your error?

Comment: @Enigmativity what Herman means is that if you run the code you supplied (the `Subscribe` method action for `OnError`) the program as a whole will still throw an exception and 'terminate' prematurely. He wants that error to he handled. The `OnError` method overload only handles errors in the source, not in the subscription. See my answer for more details.