# onError not working in subscribe observable c#

Tags: c#, reactive-programming

i have this code(sample source code from [sample code](https://reactiveui.net/reactive-extensions/creating/creating))

i change a little this code for get exception with onError like :

```
  IObservable<int> source = Observable.Range(1, 10);
        IDisposable subscription = source.Subscribe<int>(
            onNext =>
            {
                int zero = 0;                //added this code
                var div = onNext / zero;     //and this code for get execption
            },
             onError =>
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("OnError: {0}", onError.Message); // This code never runs
            });
        subscription.Dispose();
```

how to set exception to onError?

Comment: FYI, the `onError` here is to catch exception errors emitted by `source`, not by your callback `onNext`.

Comment: when my operation in onNext what expection happen to source?

Comment: how i can handle onNext Exception without try/catch and if?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onError` here is supposed to catch exception errors emitted by `source`, not by your callback `onNext`.

I would say the `try ... catch` inside `onNext` is the usual way to go here, though it's understandable that you want to reuse your error handling in `onError`.

If you want to force this pattern here, what you could do is to pipe your observable to another that executes the code you want to catch, with a `Do` for instance, and subscribe to the result observable.

something like :

```
IObservable<int> source = Observable.Range(1, 10);

IDisposable subscription = source.Do(_ =>
    {
        // Here goes the code you had in your 'onNext' originally
        throw new Exception("Throw exception manually for test purposes.");
    })
    .Subscribe(
        _ => { /* nothing to do */ },
        error =>
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("OnError: {0}", error.Message);
        }
    );
```

Related Q&A : [How to handle exceptions in OnNext when using ObserveOn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182371/how-to-handle-exceptions-in-onnext-when-using-observeon)
(I don't think this is an exact duplicate, but a part overlaps with this question, IMO)